# How can I make two JOptionPane's show up together on my first page and have a loop listen for correct answers on both?

Tags: java

I am working on a class project where I need to make an "Ice Cream Shop" that allows input for 1-3 scoops and picks a flavor which then draws an ice cream cone as well as a receipt for the ice cream. I'm getting stuck pretty early on trying to get my inputs for scoops/flavors figured out.

I'm wondering is setting up a JPanel is necessary to get the options to show up together and what is the best way to have a line of code that listens for the input to lead to the desired output of an ice cream cone and receipt?

```
public void createGUI() {
    ImageIcon icon = new 
ImageIcon(IceCreamTemplate.class.getResource("storefront.jpeg")); 
//creates image icon
    userNumber = 
Integer.parseInt((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many 
scoops would you like?", "Ice Cream Order", 
JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, icon, null, null)); //asks initial 
question

    Object[] options = {"option1", "option2", "option3"};
    //...and passing `frame` instead of `null` as first parameter
    Object selectionObject = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose", "Menu", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
    String selectionString = selectionObject.toString();
}
```

I would like to have a text input for the user to enter 1-3 scoops and a drop down menu that will eventually select flavors of ice cream and the output to lead to a painted cone based on selections with a receipt for the cone.

Comment: I think you want one dialog with both your selections on it. JOptionPane's purpose is to make it very easy to display a small dialog with a limited purpose, and your purpose is beyond what was intended to be done with it. Attempting to listen to two of them is more complicated, both for the programmer and the user, than the problem calls for. Make one JDialog with the options the way you want them, create a method that displays that dialog and returns an object representing the choice made (including 'Cancel'!).

Comment: I will look into doing it this way! Thank you for the recommendation, I'm pretty new to this.